# Bootstrap 4 with rotating cards

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am creating my own card using Bootstrap v4 (with only rows and columns). The problem is when I try to put the two sides of the card on top of each other. I use `position: absolute;` They disappear completely

```css
.thecard {
  perspective: 150rem;
  -moz-perspective: 150rem;
  position: relative;
}

.thecard__side {
  background-color: orangered;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 2rem;
  height: 50rem;
  transition: all .8s;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.thecard__side--front {
  background-color: orangered;
}

.thecard__side--back {
  background-color: green;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.thecard:hover .thecard__side--front {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.thecard:hover .thecard__side--back {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(0);
  transform: rotateY(0);
}
```

```html
<div class="row mt-5">
  <div class="mt-5 mt-lg-0 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
    <div class="thecard">
      <div class="thecard__side thecard__side--front">
        Front
      </div>
      <div class="thecard__side thecard__side--back">
        Back
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="mt-5 mt-lg-0 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
    <div class="thecard">
      <div class="thecard__side thecard__side--front">
        Front
      </div>
      <div class="thecard__side thecard__side--back">
        Back
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class=" offset-md-3 mt-5 mt-lg-0 offset-lg-0 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
    <div class="thecard">
      <div class="thecard__side thecard__side--front">
        Front
      </div>
      <div class="thecard__side thecard__side--back">
        Back
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

any solution guys?

Comment: it works perfect for me... when screen is md size there are tow divs side by side

Comment: I just knew the reason, the height of the card side collapsed and there is no height at all, I fixed it by adding the same height to the parent, which is .thecard class.

Answer (score 0):

After multiple testing, the same height on both these classes fixed the issue for me:

```
 .thecard {
      perspective: 150rem;
      -moz-perspective: 150rem;
      position: relative;
      height: 50rem; 
    }

    .thecard__side {
      background-color: orangered;
      color: #fff;
      font-size: 2rem;
      height: 50rem;
      transition: all .8s;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      backface-visibility: hidden;
    }
```

Comment: Glad to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

**You Can Try This Code**

```css
.thecard {
  perspective: 150rem;
  -moz-perspective: 150rem;
  position: relative;
  height: 350px;
}

.thecard__side {
  background-color: orangered;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 2rem;
  height: 50rem;
  transition: all .8s;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.thecard__side--front {
  background-color: orangered;
}

.thecard__side--back {
  background-color: green;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.thecard:hover .thecard__side--front {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.thecard:hover .thecard__side--back {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(0);
  transform: rotateY(0);
}
```

```html
<div class="row mt-5">
  <div class="mt-5 mt-lg-0 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
    <div class="thecard">
      <div class="thecard__side thecard__side--front">
        Front
      </div>
      <div class="thecard__side thecard__side--back">
        Back
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="mt-5 mt-lg-0 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
    <div class="thecard">
      <div class="thecard__side thecard__side--front">
        Front
      </div>
      <div class="thecard__side thecard__side--back">
        Back
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class=" offset-md-3 mt-5 mt-lg-0 offset-lg-0 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
    <div class="thecard">
      <div class="thecard__side thecard__side--front">
        Front
      </div>
      <div class="thecard__side thecard__side--back">
        Back
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```